# Styling Button in AURA COMPONENTS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, css, style

How can I apply CSS Styles to an Aura button? Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<lightning:button class="other-devices-button" label="Close" title="Close action" onclick="{! c.closeModalOtherDevices }"/>
```

CSS:

```
    .THIS .other-devices-button{
        
            --sds-c-button-brand-color-background: purple;
        
}
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In Aura, you cannot use styling hooks. You need to remove spaces from your `.THIS .other-devices-button`.

So your final component should look like.

```
<lightning:button class="other-devices-button" label="Close" title="Close action" onclick="{! c.closeModalOtherDevices }"/>
```

### css

```
.THIS.other-devices-button{
    background-color: purple;
}
```

And in UI it will look like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes you can try this :

```
<lightning:button label="Close" title="Close action" onclick="{! c.closeModalOtherDevices }" class="other-devices-button"/>
```

and go to your css file :

```
.THIS .uiButton.other-devices-button{
   background-color: #E6E6FA    ;
   padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Still not working...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the new CSS Style Hooks only work in LWC, not Aura. You'd need to write a custom LWC component to engage with this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color by following below line of .Cmp and Style file.

```
<lightning:button class="other-devices-button" label="Close" title="Close action"/>
```

Please add space in between .THIS and your class name .other-devices-button

.THIS .other-devices-button {
background-color: red    ;
padding: 10px 20px;
}